# Dynamic java script zoom error in vb.net project

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, dynamic, zooming

I inherited a legacy VB.net project that always has the following error:

```
document.body.style.zoom = screen.logicalXDPI / screen.deviceXDPI;
```

The exact error message from VIsual Studio is as follows:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
```

I have searched the entire solution, but none of the relevant variables/attributes show up.

I assume this is a javascript or jquery problem, the debugger says that it is a script block [dynamic] and the Call Stack says that it is global code.

Has anyone seen this error before?

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, removing add-ins in the browser did the trick (thanks to a colleague).  It's not in the code-base at all in this case.  The specific culprit was a MacAfee add-in.  I never would have guessed this.